# Distributed headless website testing using opentest

Tags: web, load, opentest

I would like to find out how to run opentest in headless mode.  I've read other posts that refer to configuration for headless mode, but I don't know how to invoke opentest from the command-line.

My goal is to load test a website by running many instances of opentest from  different ec2 instances.  If this is not the right way to do a load test, I would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4JVZ-V76uo about using Opentest with Jenkins.

The command line is:

```
opentest session create --template <template_path> --wait --out <test_results_path>
```

The  is relative to the templates directory.

The actor config needed these chrome args:

```
chromeDriverExeArgs: [--start   -maximized, --ignore-certificate-errors, headless]
```